# Awesome Print a Ruby Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, output, awesomeprint

I am trying to output a hash which is the result of calling Flickr's collection.getTree method.

I have:

```
ap @flickr_collections
```

It IS printing out the hash but with all the escaped html tags around it. How can I get around this. I did try `.html_safe` but it didn't work.

Basically all I want is a nice pretty printed output of this hash. Nothing more nothing less.

UPDATE:

This is what I am running: `= ap(@flickr_collections, html: true)`

and the output is:

```
<pre class="debug_dump">{ <pre>&quot;collections&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;collection&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre>[ <kbd style="color:white">[0] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;set&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre>[ <kbd style="color:white">[0] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629511800621&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;On-Ride Photography&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[1] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629391565747&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;First Day with Flash, Rocket &amp; Piper&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre> ]</pre>, <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;57928212-72157629836236274&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Misc&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;iconlarge&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;/images/collection_default_l.gif&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;iconsmall&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;/images/collection_default_s.gif&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[1] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;collection&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre>[ <kbd style="color:white">[0] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;set&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre>[ <kbd style="color:white">[ 0] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629683535562&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 1 - Hollywood Tour and Santa Monica Pier&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 1] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629683541696&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 2 - Drive to Bay Area&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 2] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629683554852&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 3 - Six Flags Discovery Kingdom&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 3] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629710465912&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 4 - Gilroy Gardens &amp; Santa Cruz Beach Boardwalk&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 4] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629710474644&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 5 - California's Great America &amp; Long Drive South&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 5] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629710489442&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 6 - Six Flags Magic Mountain&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 6] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629834618028&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 7 - Universal Studios Hollywood &amp; Scandia Amusement Park &amp; John's Incredible Pizza&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 7] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629834637138&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 8 - Sea World San Diego &amp; Belmont Park&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 8] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629836419418&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 9 - Legoland California &amp; Castle Amusement Park&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 9] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629851123596&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 10 - Knott's Berry Farm &amp; Adventure City&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[10] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629851700916&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 11 &amp; 12 - Disneyland Resort&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[11] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629851713058&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 13,14 &amp; 15 - Las Vegas&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre> ]</pre>, <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;57928212-72157629691182748&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;West Coast Tour 2009&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;iconlarge&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;/images/collection_default_l.gif&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;iconsmall&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;/images/collection_default_s.gif&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[1] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;set&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre>[ <kbd style="color:white">[ 0] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629866337538&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 0 - Arrival and Mall of America&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 1] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629868655454&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 1 - Mall of America&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 2] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629970737598&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 2 - Adventureland and Worlds of Fun&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 3] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630011649024&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 3 - Worlds of Fun&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 4] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630034790528&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 4 - Silver Dollar City&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 5] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630035520246&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 5 - St Louis Arch and City Museum&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 6] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630043090072&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 6 - Six Flags St Louis&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 7] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630043098290&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 7 - Holiday World&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 8] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630048416804&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 8 - Indiana Beach&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 9] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630048431390&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 9 - Six Flags Great America&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[10] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157629997482351&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 10 - Mount Olympus, Timber Falls and Knuckleheads&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[11] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630059600702&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 11 - Valleyfair&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre> ]</pre>, <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;57928212-72157629866347760&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Middle America Tour 2010&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;iconlarge&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;/images/collection_default_l.gif&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;iconsmall&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;/images/collection_default_s.gif&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[2] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;set&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre>[ <kbd style="color:white">[0] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157631693409808&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 1 - Great Wall of China, Tiananmen Square, Forbidden City&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[1] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630657898798&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 1 - Carowinds&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[2] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630692436584&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 2 - Dollywood&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[3] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630699845912&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 3 - Random Pigeon Forge Activities&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[4] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630714758818&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 4 - Long Drive to Williamsburg&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[5] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630717785454&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 5 - Busch Gardens Williamsburg&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[6] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157630717785576&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 6 - Kings Dominion&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre> ]</pre>, <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;57928212-72157630658165668&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;IntimidaTOUR 2010&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;iconlarge&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;/images/collection_default_l.gif&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;iconsmall&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;/images/collection_default_s.gif&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[3] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;set&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre>[ <kbd style="color:white">[ 0] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157631693011733&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 0 - Early Arrival Day, Crab Island Childrens Amusement Park, Crab Island Amusement Park, Aoyun Fuwa Eden, Beijing World Park&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 1] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157631693409808&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 1 - Great Wall of China, Tiananmen Square, Forbidden City&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 2] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157631698474564&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 2 - Shijingshan Amusement Park, Sun Park&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 3] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157631703216195&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 3 - Happy Valley Beijing and visit to 2008 Olympic Park&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 4] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157631713251068&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;Day 4 - Victory Kingdom, Children's Palace, Langfang&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;description&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;&quot;</kbd></pre> }</pre>, <kbd style="color:white">[ 5] </kbd><pre>{ <pre>&quot;id&quot;</pre><kbd style="color:slategray"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style="color:brown">&quot;72157631761492087&quot;</kbd></pre>, <pre>&quot;title&quot;</pre>
```

I can;t add the rest of the output as I can only use 30,000 characters in this box. The above is the first part of the output.

If I add a raw call infront of `ap`, then it does help but it outputs each string, hash arrow and curly brace/square brace on a new line which is no use whatsoever.

I would appreciate this question being reopened.

Comment: not sure if it will work but try using the raw method. If you are using Rails...

Comment: This helped but put every single item on a new line so it's not very helpful

Comment: It'd be helpful if you showed what output you're getting, and what output you desire.

Comment: Without output you're asking us to guess and imagine what it could be, which is worthless. Please add that information to the question so we know what you're seeing. Otherwise, your question is ambiguous, vague and incomplete, which makes it likely it'd get closed.

Comment: No problem. I will add my output once I am back at home. Jees Why do people close things so quickly. You hardly give people a chance to recover from mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `strip_tags`?

See doc: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Comment: That doesn't work either. Just tried it in the console and it doesn't work either!

Comment: Yeah I got it the first time :P Can you post your hash? and the result?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print this in a view? Have you tried

```
ap(@flickr_collections, :html => true)
```

Comment: Will try this later once I am back at home.